# How to select the correct Bolt/screw Torque for sealing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, plastic, seals

My coworkers and I are finally testing our agriculture sensor on the field. As you can imagine, the moisture and dust are important variables to keep aside from the electronics inside our product. Therefore we now want to take into consideration the sealing more seriously. 
The case of our product is made of Polypropylene, and a gasket generates the seal. We want to purchase an adjustable torque screwdriver for the sealing, but I don't have any idea of the torque range we need. Of course, we want to create an airtight seal and avoid damaging the case plastic thread.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dial gauge and an adjustable torque wrench / screwdriver, then measure the compression of the seal compared to the torque applied - keep increasing torque setting until compression is sufficient for purpose without exceeding the thread capacity.